# Unknown CUDA error when importing theano

Tags: python, cuda, ubuntu-14.04, theano-cuda

In python, after importing theano, I get the following:

```
In [1]: import theano
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  
(error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: unknown error)
```

I'm running this on ubuntu 14.04 and I have an old gpu: GeForce GTX280

And my nvidia driver:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Wed Jul 13 21:25:58 2016       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.96     Driver Version: 340.96         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 280     Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   65C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    638MiB /  1023MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm not sure why it's saying it's 'Not Supported' but it seems as though that might not be an issue as said [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/697308/compute-processes-not-supported/)

Also, the CUDA version:

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
```

Any help I can get would be awesome. I've been at this all day...

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. I spent a few days ploughing through all the CUDA related errors.

Firstly, update to a more recent driver. eg, 361. (CLEAN INSTALL IT!) Then completely wipe cuda and cudnn from your harddrive with

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda
```

or wherever else you installed it, then install cuda 7.5 (seriously, this specific version) and cuDNN v4 (again, this specific version)

You can run the following commands to settle CUDA.

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/local_installers/cuda_7.5.18_linux.run
bash cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --override
```

Follow the instructions, **say NO when they ask you to install the 350 driver**. And you should be set.

For cudnn, there's no direct link to wget, so you have to get the installer from https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn and run the following commands:

```
tar xvzf cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include
sudo cp -r cuda/lib64/. /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64

echo -e 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64"\nexport CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now to handle Theano on GPU:

```
nano ~/.theanorc
```

add these lines:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0
```

If you get an nvcc error, make it so instead:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0
[nvcc]
flags=-D_FORCE_INLINES
```

Comment: The reason I was using CUDA 6.5 and driver 340.96 was that my gpu isn't compatible with later NVIDIA drivers. Anyways, I just updated the hardware (because it was easier) and then installed CUDA 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to solve my issue by doing two things:

- Install gcc-5 and linking/usr/bin/gcc to /usr/bin/gcc-5 as well as /usr/bin/g++ to/usr/bin/g++-5 (PS: I am using cuda 8)
- Adding this flag flags=-D_FORCE_INLINES to the file ~/.theanorc under nvcc since apparently a bug in glibc 2.23 causes this issue